# How can I get a value out of a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I am returning some data *(example below)* and saving it to a jQuery object *(or is this an array and I am confusing the two?)* when I log the variable that is the object it has the values I am looking for but how do I access the data inside this object?

**code**

```
$itemPosition = {
    'top': $item.offset().top,
    'left':$item.offset().left
},

console.log($itemPosition);
```

This would log out *(the in this case expected)* `top: 0` & `left: 490`.

But how can I know work with those values?

*Also, while this it is probably obvious I am still in the early stages of learning jQuery/Javascript rest assured that reference books are on their way, but so far the SO community has been invaluable to my learning, so thanks for reading!*

J.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a plain javascript object. Not a jQuery object and not an array.

Accessing properties of an object would work like so:

```
 $itemPosition.top;
 $itemPosition.left;
```

Placing a `$` as the first character of the name is valid, but may lead to confusion as it is a convention used when storing a jQuery object.

Another valid way to access the properties of your object is to use square brackets, as in:

```
 $itemPosition['top'];
 $itemPosition['left'];
```

Using the square bracket method, you can also pass in variables, like so:

```
var myTopString = 'top';

$itemPosition[myTopString];
```

If you want to iterate over all the values in your object, you can do the following:

```
for(var n in $itemPosition) {
    alert( n + ': ' + $itemPosition[n] );
}
```

This will `alert()` the key and value of each object property. As you can see, it uses the square bracket method, passing in the key for each property stored in the variable `n`.

*That's all I have to say about that. -F. Gump*

Comment: +1 - and I would further stress the point that your var should probably be named `itemPosition` not `$itemPosition`.  **Most** jQuery code uses the `$` prefix on `$item` as a way of labeling the variable as a jQuery object I.E. - `var $item = $('#theitem");`

Comment: @gnarf - Indeed. Even in the short example, caught me off guard for a second.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer. I have adjusted my script and also removed the `$` symbol which I will from here on out only use for actual jQuery objects. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you can just use properties:

```
$itemPosition = {
    'top': $item.offset().top,
    'left':$item.offset().left
},

console.log($itemPosition.top);
console.log($itemPosition.left);
```

All you've done is create a javascript variable called `$itemPosition` with an anonymous type.  It has two properties called `top` and `left`.